# Retrieve Data from sql table to datagridview in combobox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have a table in sql and its columns are: ID, EmpNo, Name and Usertype.

How to retrieve the data in Usertpye column to datagridview combo box

only the Usertype is a combobox

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on how you are populatng the DGV

Comment: Do you mean below? 1) Bind Usertype column value to combobox 2) Place that combobox inside the datagridview.

Comment: How to place it in the datagridview?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, I hope you want something like that.

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

string sqlConnection = "Data Source";
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(sqlConnection);
conn.Open();
//Get bind from database.
string qryGetCategory = "Query to get data for combo box";
SqlCeCommand cmdCat = new SqlCeCommand(qryGetCategory, conn);
SqlCeDataAdapter daCat = new SqlCeDataAdapter(qryGetCategory, conn);
DataTable dtCat = new DataTable();
daCat.Fill(dtCat);

//Combobox column.
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ComboBoxCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
ComboBoxCol.DataSource = dtCat;
ComboBoxCol.Name = "Column name";
ComboBoxCol.ValueMember = "Value of member";
ComboBoxCol.DisplayMember = "Member to be show";
datagridview.Columns.Add(ComboBoxCol);
```

In case you have any problem or query please feel free to ask me.

Comment: @LeoJb, If you find it helpful please mark it as answer so it will help others's too